# How do I compare two string value Absolutely in sql?

Tags: sql, comparison

I am trying to figure out how to compare two string value for an absolute match. I.E. "Abc" <> "abc".

"Abc" is in a row in an SQL(Usr)  and "abc" is variable value.

When I run this - "Select Count(*) from UserTable where UserName = '" & Usr & "'" & " and Password = '" & Pwd & "'" - it tells me the two values are identical.

I can't figure out how to get an absolute comparison??

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim Usr As String, Pwd As String
   
   Usr = TextBox1.Text.Trim
   Pwd = TextBox2.Text.Trim
   
   Dim i As Integer

   user_stmt = "Select Count(*) from UserTable where UserName = '" & Usr & "'" & " and Password = '"        & Pwd & "'"

   User_Cmd = New SqlCommand(user_stmt, con)
  
   con.Open()

   i = User_Cmd.ExecuteScalar()

   Stop

   If i = 1 Then
      MsgBox("Found")
   Else
      MsgBox("Exit")
   End If
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: It depends on the collation used. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Dont use string concatenation to build your sql string, use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection and other issues(especially if your parameters come from user input like here). Also: don't store passwords as plain text but encrypt them.

Comment: If you're asking how to do something in SQL then the application language is irrelevant. The SQL you use will be the same regardless.

Answer (score 1):

There are several very important things to consider and correct in your code:

**SQL Injection Risk:**

Your code is susceptible to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Never concatenate string values directly into SQL statements. Use parameterized queries instead.

**Case Sensitivity in SQL:**

If you want a case-sensitive comparison, you need to force a binary comparison by appending COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN to your comparison.

**Storing Passwords:**

Do not store plain text passwords in the database. Always [**store a salted**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) hash of the password and compare the hashes. **Plain text password storage is a serious security risk.**

heres a potential fix for your issue: (no hashing with salts, but you can easily find functions to do that for you)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim Usr As String, Pwd As String
   
   Usr = TextBox1.Text.Trim
   Pwd = TextBox2.Text.Trim
   
   Dim i As Integer

   user_stmt = "SELECT Count(*) FROM UserTable WHERE UserName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = @UserName AND Password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = @Password"

   User_Cmd = New SqlCommand(user_stmt, con)
   User_Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Usr)
   User_Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Pwd)
  
   con.Open()

   i = User_Cmd.ExecuteScalar()

   con.Close()

   If i = 1 Then
      MsgBox("Found")
   Else
      MsgBox("Exit")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; very much appreciated.

Comment: Note that Latin1_General_BIN  is a product specific collation - for a dbms not specified...